# How can i call upon my variable $ADUser to filter into tables?

Tags: windows, powershell, script, active-directory, file-filter

```
$ADUsers = Import-csv "C:\DC_Share\DC-IT\Scripts\200+ Mumbai New hires V2 (1).csv" ;

Get-ADUsers -filter * -properties * | select-object samaccountname, givenname,office, surname, password,streetaddress,st,physicalDeliveryOfficeName,manager,mail,title,company,whenCreated | Format-Table
```

Comment: Don't work with Active Directory, but I know the cmdlet is `Get-ADUser`, not `Get-ADUsers`....

Comment: Also, into what tables? Just in the PowerShell terminal output like the command example you provided but where you control each `SamAccountName` from the csv you already have to run the `Get-ADUser` command with those selected properties from it's output for just those accounts in your csv list?